# Weird bed movement when doing ABL (G29)

Tags: automatic-bed-leveling

My printer recently started lowering the bed an additional step for every measurement on the `G29` procedure. The only change I did, at least purposely is, adjusting the nozzle offset and MIN/MAX positions for X and Y because I installed the "Hero Me" parts.

Here's a video of what happens:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it turned out, it is actually a bug: https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues/25565